# Prove that there is an annihilator integer in a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with $1 \in R$. Multiplication by a positive integer $k$ means
>   multiple addition $ka = a + a + ... + a$. Suppose the positive integer $n$ is such that $n1 = 0$ in $R$. Show that $na = 0$ for every $a \in R$.

It seems to be easy task, but I have not managed to find an appropiate proof of this. For example writing $na=a+a+...+a$, $a1=1a=a \in R$, can I have $na=n(1a)=(n1)a=0a=0$? I believe that this would follow if $n \in R$ (its the multiplication associativity) but that's not the case here. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is basically correct, but I guess it would help you if you just write it out: 
$$na = a +\ldots +a = 1\cdot a +\ldots +1\cdot a = (1 +\ldots +1)\cdot a = 0\cdot a = 0.$$
So apart from the properties of 1 and 0, we only use the distributivity property that holds in $R$.

Comment: You were faster, so you  get the credit for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your equalities are correct, but with incorrect reasoning, since $$ na = a+a+\ldots +a = (1+1\ldots +1)a = (n1)a =0a =0$$

Comment: Last equation is probably $a$ instead of $n$. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that is correct.